# Do something when page is scrolling and have some position

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, position

i have a little problem with page scrolling... 
I wanna to change some css when i'm scrolling page down and if window have 100px from top position...
This is my code. Much thx for help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scroll(100)){
            $('.ufo').css('right','800px');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(window).scroll(100)` This is not doing what you think it should Read the docs.

Comment: it is very unlikely the scroll position is ever going to hit 100 exactly so making it greater than 100 would be your best bet as gdoron said :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
            $('.ufo').css('right','800px');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: one other question, how to bind this event now, so when i will be back to top this function starts again?