# Teleport a div using jquery while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if it is possible to "teleport" a div into another part of the DOM using jQuery on scrolling.

For example, let's say I have an article:

Title

```
Subt 1
Div area 1
Content 1
```

Where `subt` is subtitle and `div area` is where the div will be included.

So I need to achieve this result:

While the user will be scrolling, the div will be jumping from area to area

```
     **-- If I scroll from here --**

Subt 1
        Div area 1 
        Content 1



       Subt 2
        Div area 2
        Content 2



       Subt 3
        Div area 3
        Content 3


    **-- To here --**
       Subt 4
        Div area 4 -- The div will appear inside of here --
        Content 4
```

I don't want the div to appear at all places at once, it's just that it will follow the scrolling moving from one area to another one. I not even know how search this in google, that's why I'm asking.

Thx in advance

Comment: You're asking how [to move an element into another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element)

Comment: Yes, but only on scrolling.

Comment: So you're also asking [how to do something on scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994909/do-something-when-page-is-scrolling-and-have-some-position) ?

Answer (score 1):

The method you'll want to use is jQuery's `detach` (https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

```
// Detach is to splice from the DOM
$SwappedElement = $('#HotSwapDiv').detach(); 
// substitute logic to determine div position by window scroll
$DestinationDivArea = $('#div_identifier)
// Append (attach to end) of Destination div
$DestinationDivArea.append( $SwappedElement );
```

You can listen to the window scroll event with the following, in jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Get current window scroll amount in pixels
  iPixelsScrolledFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  // Get the amount from the top of one of your divs
  iDivAreaPixelsFromTop = $('#div_identifier').offset().top;
  // Arbitrary calculation to see if target div is 250 pixels away from scroll
  if( iPixelsScrolledFromTop > (iDivAreaPixelsFromTop - 250) )
    :> //Insert swap logic from above
});
```

Comment: no need to use detach... doing an append already takes it from original location to put it in new location

Comment: You guys got a fiddle to serve as example?